# saving multiple files through xcopy

Tags: command-line, xcopy

i want to copy multiple files at once through xcopy. is it possible. i mean something like:
xcopy file1+file2+file3 destinationfolder
any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with a single xcopy, but you could use a for statement.
Something like:
for %f in (file1, file2, filen) do xcopy %f dest\

Comment: i dont know how to use it. can u plz give the exact syntax? that would be really helpful

Comment: this *is* the answer.  
The for command iterates through the list of files (specified in brackets) and executes the command that appears after the "do" keyword.  
Try typing `for /?` on the command line for more information

Comment: To use the FOR command in a **batch** program, specify **%%variable** instead of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different from %I.

Answer (score 3):

for %f in (file1,file2,file3) do xcopy %f destinationfolder

Comment: To use the FOR command in a **batch** program, specify **%%variable** instead of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different from %I.

Answer (score 1):

if your files starts with  a specific pattern, you can use wildcards (eg text files that starts with file)

```
copy file*.txt e:\destination
```

Comment: I needed to copy a specific pattern so I appreciate that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used the following for copying hundreds of files and filtering them by file extension. Below I am saying give me all files with the file extension .dll, .exe, or .pdf

```
for %f in (dll,exe,pdf) do xcopy /s /i C:\source\*.%f C:\destination
```

Comment: To use the FOR command in a **batch** program, specify **%%variable** instead of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different from %I.

Answer (score 0):

`xcopy` will only copy one file from source to destination assuming you know the file to copy and you know the destination:

```bash
xcopy .\bin\Debug\Application.exe .\Deploy
```

But if you still want to copy with wildcard you need to use the for loop to enumerate all the files and then tell the `xcopy` to copy it from source to destination.

For Example: the following will copy `.dll` & `.exe` from `.\bin\Debug` to `.\Deploy`

```bash
for /r ".\bin\Debug" %%f in (*.dll, *.exe) do xcopy /y "%%f" ".\Deploy"
```

Here assuming your command prompt is in directory `Test`:

- `for` is the keyword for the `for each loop`
- `/r` is for recursive search for folders and sub folders
- `.\bin\Debug` is the folder where current folder is represented with `.` for `Test\bin\Debug`
- `%%f` is the filename with path
- `*.dll` & `*.exe` represent all exe & dll in the folder `.\bin\Debug`
- `do` represent the action
- `xcopy` is the action
- `/y` is to say yes to `xcopy` prompt asking for confirmation
- `"%%f"` is the filepath enclosed in quotes to mitigate spaces as this is the source parameter to `xcopy`
- `.\Deploy` is the destination folder like `Test\Deploy`

A rather better approach is to use `robocopy` as

```bash
robocopy "C:\Test\bin\Debug" "D:\Test\Deploy" *.dll
```